# Limits of the derangements proportion within the permutations of the set $[1,n]$

Tags: sequences-and-series, analysis, limits

> Let be $D_n$ the number of derangements of a set of $n$ elements, by convention we have $D_0=1$

Ifound that $D_n=n!\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$

> For all $n\in \mathbb{N*}$, we write $p_n$ the derangements proportion within the permutations of the set $[1,n]$
>
> Find $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow+\infty}p_n$

- From the definition of $p_n$ we have
  $$p_n=\frac{D_n}{n!}=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{(-1)^k}{k!}$$
- Yet, $\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$

$$\sum\limits_{n=0}^{+\infty}\frac{z^n}{n!}=e^z$$

- Thus from last equality for $z=1$, we have:

$$p_n\longrightarrow_{n \rightarrow +\infty}\frac{1}{e}$$

I don't understand where does these two last points come from. Can you help me understanding them?

Answer (score 1):

The second point is (one of) the definition(s) of the exponential function.

The last one is obtained from the second by taking $z=-1$.